# Count number of rows Lua

Tags: count, lua

I'm doing a project that involves file reading and I need to know the exact number of row in the file. Does anyone know how to count the number of rows in a file without having to read the whole file? I mean is there a built-in function for that in Lua? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no magic way to know how many line a file has. This is determined only by how many newline `\n` characters there are in the file. So there is no way to know that without reading the whole file. So the only way is to use a loop as Egor Skriptunoff wrote in his answer. Though hardly ever one needs to know just line count wihtouh processing the actual lines. Can you tell us what you need that number for?

Answer (score 7):

Lua has built-in file lines iterator.
Very convenient.
Recommended for using. :-)

```
local ctr = 0
for _ in io.lines'filename.txt' do
  ctr = ctr + 1
end
```

Comment: The OP wants to "count without having to read the whole file".

Comment: @lhf - Does some OS exist which caches lines counters for every file on disk?  If not, OP's question should be interpreted as "How to get lines counter without writing long code in Lua?"

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Fair enough, but you should explain in your answer that the information simply doesn't exist without reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function for that. The only way is to read the whole file, as in Egor's answer for instance.